# How to filter records with multiple conditions with start date and end date

Tags: javascript

I am requesting the following array from my server in my angular 7 applicaiton.

```
var data =  [{
  "ProjectID": "09fbeda6-860e-11e9-a8cd-38607725a846",
  "StartDate": "2018-12-11T18:30:00.000Z",
  "EndDate": "2019-01-11T18:30:00.000Z",
  "Name": "Test filters"
},
{
  "ProjectID": "01418e66-85f3-11e9-a8cd-38607725a846",
  "StartDate": "2019-06-02T18:30:00.000Z",
  "EndDate": "2019-06-27T18:30:00.000Z",
  "Name": "Sang"
},
{
  "ProjectID": "ad38f7ce-85e7-11e9-a8cd-38607725a846",
  "StartDate": "2019-06-02T18:30:00.000Z",
  "EndDate": "2019-11-28T18:30:00.000Z",
  "Name": "Arun_Viewer_test"
}];
```

and i have a below function , it will accept dynamic keys and values to filter data.

```
filterBy = { Name: ["Filters"]}; // to search based on dynamic key and value
 result = data.filter(function (o) { 
    return Object.keys(filterBy).every(function (k) {
        return filterBy[k].some(function (f) {
            return (o[k].toLowerCase()).includes(f.toLowerCase());
        });
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

alternate way with ES6 which provide same output as above function

```
result = data.filter(o => Object.keys(filterBy).every(k => filterBy[k].some(f => (o[k].toLowerCase()).includes(f.toLowerCase()))));
```

in the console result is printing and the function is working fine.

**but i would like to filter items whether they are between given startdate and enddate , it should contain project name.**
**In short words i have to apply two filters project should contain given name  and project should between  given startdate and enddate like below**

```
filterBy = { Name: ["Filters"], StartDate: ["new Date(12/31/2018)"], EndDate: ["new Date(31/07/2019)"]}
```

Comment: You should avoid sorting with strings like this, as code minification might become an issue. [More information](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe).

Comment: Not usefull and it will not resolve my question

Comment: You'll see once you deploy your project.

Comment: then how can i resolve my issue

Comment: By not making it dynamic, as I've just stated.

Comment: i did production build , minification done properly and without any issues

Comment: Is it coming from your server ?

Comment: yes coming from server

Comment: Okay. If you want to sort/filter on different conditions, then you need to implement the said conditions. You can't magically filter between two dates, for that, you will have to use some keys, something like [firebase queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#where)

Answer (score -1):

Not the most optimal but [this should work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-szkabv) in your case.

- Structure your filter criteria into a key value pair array.
- Filter records with this structure as predicate for filter.

const filterCriteria = [{key: 'Name', value: 'blah'}, {key: 'StartDate', value: 'blah1'}, {key: 'EndDate', value: 'blah2'}];

```
const filteredValues = records.filter(record => {
    let filtered = true;
        filterCriteria.forEach(criteria => {
        if (filtered && record[criteria.key] !== criteria.value) {
            filtered = false;
        }
    })
    return filtered;
});
```

This solution can be improved with higher order functions.

Comment: Fixed the if block. Works now. Linked to working page on stackblitz.